# How does Shield Bash (Shattered Shield) work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

[Shield Bash (Shattered Shield)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/shield-bash) states that it hits "for 325% weapon damage plus 300% of your shield's Block Chance as damage." I'm not exactly clear on what this means. If I have a block chance of 20%, does that mean my damage calculation goes as follows:

`325% weapon damage + (300% * Block Chance) = 325% weapon damage + 0.6`

That feels like a comically small improvement (less than 1 damage) as to seem completely useless.

Comment: Well, a perfect stormshield has 34% block chance, that would be 102% bonus, or 427% for SB (SS). Also, the crusader passive that adds Shield's block chance to armor could increase it by 34% similarly.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey that's correct.  Its a shame the passive only uses the shield's base block % so any modifiers to boost block % will not bump up armor.

Comment: @z- I agree. I thought the passive would be super fun to build around if it was based on your block chance and not the shields, but it does specify that language in the skill description. I tested it by equipping and removing a Justice Lantern ring. There are still skills that are fun with 100% block chance like "Renewal" passive and then "Coven's Criterion" and "Salvation" shields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using your shield block chance's % as a multiplier.

For example, if your shield has 20% block chance, then Shattering Shield will do 325% + 60% damage for a total of 385% damage.